# List of data frames to nested list based on names - R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames like this:

```
dflist <- list(
  X2013.11.14.Date = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))), X2013.11.14.Treatment = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))),
  X2013.11.14.Value = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))), X2014.08.12.Date = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))),
  X2014.08.12.Treatment = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))), X2014.08.12.Value = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:1,5,rep=TRUE))))
```

Within the list, each data frame is named with a date combined with a description like this:

```
names(dflist)
#[1] "X2013.11.14.Location"      "X2013.11.14.Treatment" "X2013.11.14.Value"    "X2014.08.12.Location"     
#[5] "X2014.08.12.Treatment" "X2014.08.12.Value"
```

I would like to combine the individual data frames into new, larger data frames using the date portion of their names (e.g. `X2013.11.14`), keeping them within the list and if possible having the date as the list element name and the description (e.g. `Location`) as the column names. I'm not even sure what to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `dplyr::bind_rows` and `tidyr::separate` arrange data in a dataframe with date/time.

This solution is in similar line of that provided by @Frank.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

bind_rows(dflist, .id = "ID") %>%
  separate(ID, c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Type"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  mutate(Year = gsub("X","",Year)) %>%
  unite( "Date", Year, Month, Day, sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) 

#          Date      Type X1 X2
# 1  2013-11-14      Date  0  0
# 2  2013-11-14      Date  0  0
# 3  2013-11-14      Date  0  1
# 4  2013-11-14      Date  0  1
# 5  2013-11-14      Date  1  0
# 6  2013-11-14 Treatment  0  0
# 7  2013-11-14 Treatment  1  0
# 8  2013-11-14 Treatment  0  0
# 9  2013-11-14 Treatment  0  0
# 10 2013-11-14 Treatment  1  0
# ...so on
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank. Yes. I should modify `Date` column to represent date format. I'll update it now.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do...

```
patt = "^X(.{10}).(.*)$"

library(data.table)
DT = rbindlist(dflist, id="name")

DT[, `:=`(
  date = as.IDate(sub(patt, "\\1", name), format = "%Y.%m.%d"),
  var = sub(patt, "\\2", name),
  name = NULL
)]
```

which gives...

```
    X1 X2       date       var
 1:  0  0 2013-11-14      Date
 2:  0  1 2013-11-14      Date
 3:  1  1 2013-11-14      Date
 4:  1  0 2013-11-14      Date
 5:  1  1 2013-11-14      Date
 6:  1  0 2013-11-14 Treatment
 7:  0  0 2013-11-14 Treatment
 8:  1  1 2013-11-14 Treatment
 9:  0  1 2013-11-14 Treatment
10:  1  0 2013-11-14 Treatment
11:  1  0 2013-11-14    Values
12:  1  1 2013-11-14    Values
13:  0  0 2013-11-14    Values
14:  1  0 2013-11-14    Values
15:  1  1 2013-11-14    Values
16:  0  1 2014-08-12      Date
17:  1  1 2014-08-12      Date
18:  1  0 2014-08-12      Date
19:  1  1 2014-08-12      Date
20:  1  1 2014-08-12      Date
21:  0  0 2014-08-12 Treatment
22:  0  0 2014-08-12 Treatment
23:  0  0 2014-08-12 Treatment
24:  0  1 2014-08-12 Treatment
25:  1  1 2014-08-12 Treatment
26:  1  0 2014-08-12     Value
27:  1  0 2014-08-12     Value
28:  0  0 2014-08-12     Value
29:  0  0 2014-08-12     Value
30:  1  0 2014-08-12     Value
    X1 X2       date       var
```

By the way, we see here that the names are not consistent (Value vs Values).

---

Why one table instead of a list with dates as names? When dates are stored as names, they are not dates -- they are just strings -- and you cannot use standard functions like `month()` or `difftime()` to work on them. If you really want a list, there's still...

```
listDT = DT[, list(tab = list(.SD)), by=date]

         date          tab
1: 2013-11-14 <data.table>
2: 2014-08-12 <data.table>
```

This way, dates are still stored correctly and you have a list of tables (in the second column). To access each table, syntax like `listDT[date == "2013-11-14", tab[[1]]]` works.